# GRUB Installation problem on Arch Linux system install

Tags: arch-linux, grub2, system-installation

I've been following the Arch Linux installation Wiki, and when trying to install grub, I either get

```
grub-install: error: failed to get canonical path of `udev`
```

Or

```
/boot doesn't look like an EFI partition
```

Thing is, sda1 is an EFI partition.

I'm lost, can anyone give me a hand?

I'm installing GRUB with

```
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot --bootloader-id=GRUB
```

fdisk gives

```
Device ID Type
sda1   ef EFI
sda2   83 Linux
sda3   82 Swap
```

None are bootable, and the partition sizes are 30gb, 430gb and 2gb respectively.

Comment: You really is using UEFI? Did you boot into legacy BIOS mode? And it says /boot isn't EFI partition, you sure you mount sda1 to there?

Comment: Definitely didn't boot into legacy mode, I'm installing completely form scratch. And I think I mounted sda1 there? How do I check?

Answer (score 0):

> None are bootable, and the partition sizes are 30gb, 430gb and 2gb respectively.

This is very wrong. Why would you have 30Gb boot partition?

In case you've mounted `/dev/sda1` as `/` of your new system, that is wrong as well. You need a separate boot partition of type EFI, formatted to FAT32.